# BinarySearchTree toString method

Tags: java, binary-search

I have my ToString method right here for my BinarySearchTree class

```
    private ArrayList<T> inorderList(ArrayList<T> values) {
        if (left != null) {
            left.inorderList(values);
        }
        values.add(data);
        if (right != null) {
            right.inorderList(values);
        }
        return values;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String returnS = "";
        ArrayList<T> values = new ArrayList<T>();
        values = inorderList(values);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            if (i != values.size()-1) {
                returnS += values.get(i) + ", ";
            }
            else {
                returnS += values.get(i);
            }
        }
        return returnS;
    }
```

This code works, but I'm pretty sure it's inefficient/ugly, and I'm wondering if it looks alright, or if there's any way I can clean up my code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Review, please provide an explanation about what the code does and tests.

Comment: the code first converts the tree into an arraylist, so I can then easier print it out.

Comment: I understand, my suggestion was about integrating an explanation and tests into your question to increase the odds of more answers.

Comment: Can I suggest asking for one review of the whole class, rather than breaking out individual methods into their own questions? You'll get better, more meaningful answers.

Comment: No need to convert the tree into an arraylist, as you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using an iterator on dynamic structures can simplify your logic and are generally good practice. The classic for-each loop: `for (int i : a)` uses an iterator under the hood. It also makes your conditional logic a bit more intuitive (while the iterator *has* a *next* token, place a comma) rather than relying on indexing. This doesn't add any performance benefit, but is something to keep in mind.

Every time you loop, you concatenate to a string. This is inefficient as `String` is immutable, and you therefore create a copy of it every time you make a change to it. `StringBuilder` was optimized for this, as a singular character is appended each time-- this results in a more optimal performance when *building* a *string* like you are doing

```
public String toString() {
    ArrayList<T> values = new ArrayList<T>();
    values = inorderList(values);
    final Iterator<T> valuesIterator = values.iterator();
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    while (valuesIterator.hasNext()) {
        out.append(valuesIterator.next());
        if (valuesIterator.hasNext()) {
            out.append(",");
        }
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: So why not then directly use StringBuilder instead of ArrayList?

Answer (score 2):

First, one sees you are still a beginner, hence first some pointer to improving code. And after that your question to general improvement, where you were correct to suspect there should be something better.

- `inorderList` returns its parameter, so can simply return `void`.
- It is better to *program against interfaces*, as then the implementation is free,
  you can later change the implementation class. You can assign `Collections.emptyList(), Collections.singletonList(), Collections.asList`.
- You can use the *diamond* operator `<>` saving repetitive typing.
- `StringBuilder` is a utility class to prevent inefficient String concatenation with `+`/`+=` (100 `+=`s would create 100 new strings, dropping 99 old strings).
- Always use `@Override` as that detects typos `public String toSting()`.
- I show below the usage of a more compact for-each loop.

So:

```
private void inorderList(List<T> values) {
    if (left != null) {
        left.inorderList(values);
    }
    values.add(data);
    if (right != null) {
        right.inorderList(values);
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    List<T> values = new ArrayList<>();
    inorderList(values);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (T value: values) {
        if (sb.length() != 0) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.values.append(value);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

A a comma separated string from multiple items, there exists a utility functions.

But let just answer your original question. Instead of collecting first a possibly huge ordered list, you can visit every node with a piece of code. There are several forms, but the latest is the `Stream<T>`.

A usage example would be:

```
    values.stream().forEach(v -> { // T v
        if (sb.length() != 0) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.values.append(v);
    });
```

But [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) is a very expressive and unavoidable class.

The implementation of the stream is more sophisticated.

```
public Stream<T> stream() {
    Stream s = Stream.of(data);
    if (left != null) {
        s = Stream.concat(left.stream(), s);
    }
    if (right != null) {
        s = Stream.concat(s, right.stream());
    }
    return s;
}
```

Realize that Stream does not start to iterate until a "final" operation is done such as `forEach`, `collect`, `count`, `sum`.

Now you could do:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    stream().forEach(v -> {
        if (sb.length() != 0) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.values.append(v);
    });
    return sb.toString();
}
```

With variations, like skipping empty strings.

```
    stream()
        .filter(Objects::notNull)  // T v. Means: v -> Objects.notNull(v).
        .map(v -> v.toString())    // T v. Or: Object::toString.
        .filter(v -> !v.isBlank()) // String v.
        .forEach(v -> {
            if (sb.length() != 0) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.values.append(v);
        });
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This is a bit much, and it is not necessary to start programming high javanese.

Comment: With a `Stream` you can just use a [joining collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: @RoToRa thanks for the link. I felt Stream already hard to digest for a beginner, in a review. But you provide again an other feature of the expressiveness of Streams. Worth learning.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sence to put all elements of a tree to a list just to put them later to string in some defined order. This task can be completed directly.
So here improoved version of toString:

```
public String toString( {
      String str="";
      if (left != null) str+=left+ ", ";
      str+=data;
      if (right != null) str+=", "+right;
      return str;
    }
```

I personaly have never heared about StringBuilder befor, so haven´t used it myself. After taking a look at the docs, solution using StringBuilder could look like this:

```
private void inorderString(StringBuilder strings) {
        if (left != null) {
            left.inorderString(strings);
            strings.add(", ");
        }
        strings.add(data);
        if (right != null) {
            strings.add(", ");
            right.inorderList(strings);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder strings = new StringBuilder();
        inorderString(strings);
        return strings.toString();
    }
```